# In remote setup, how can I accurately put an apostrophe in the SSID name for wpa_supplicant.conf file?

Tags: raspbian, remote, headless, wpa-supplicant

I'm trying to setup a raspberry 3 B+ headless by writing a wpa_supplicant.conf and adding to the boot directory of pi.

However, my pi keeps not connecting to my internet, and I believe its because my wifi's name is "Bob's wifi" (Bob's not the real name) and the apostrophe in it keeps getting messed up.

I've done lot of google searches and tried \u2019, \xe2\x80\x99. I've also tried escaping the apostrophe by ', ' "'"', but they all didn't work.

Then, I went to powershell on my laptop and used "netsh wlan show interfaces" to see how the SSID was printed there, and it showed "Bobâ?Ts wifi", while profile printed it just fine as "Bob's wifi".

I understand that this happens because powershell is reading the bytes not using UTF-8 but through some other encoding system, but I'm still lost and don't know what to do.

I know I can change the wifi name, but I really want to figure out the solution to this problem since I tried so much anyway. I would appreciate any help.

I've been using this string as wpa_supplicant.conf

```
country=US 
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
network={
    ssid="wifi"
    psk="password"
    scan_ssid=1
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `ssid="Bob\'s wifi"`

Comment: I think you're looking in the wrong place for your error. `?, ", $, [, \, ], and +` are the disallowed characters. Space and full stop are valid. Nothing says apostrophe's are disallowed.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried both just now, but they didn't work however.

Comment: Perhaps is this method of remote control no longer supported?

Comment: The fact that powershell shows the ssid as `Bobâ?Ts wifi` means that it is NOT `Bob's wifi` - i.e. it is NOT an apostrophe

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are trying to connect to an iPhone (which you should mention).

If so the character is **NOT** an apostrophe - it is another Unicode character. If you search my answers in this Forum you will find a suggestion, but it is far easier to change the iPhone to a sensible SSID.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The wifi was a google wifi, but as the name was typed with an iPhone that makes sense. I've tried looking through your answers, but there were too many to go through.

Comment: I will definitely switch my SSID name, but I'm really curious if there is a way to use â?T to find the right unicode for the iPhone symbol? One thing I've tried is finding the hex numbers for â?T according to Windows 1252 page, which gave me e2 3f 54, but this did not match with Unicode or UTF-8. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: I found the post I think you were referring to: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41069/how-do-i-configure-wpa-supplicant-with-default-iphone-ssid. I did find this before and tried the methods you suggested, but both of them didn't work for me. Is there another solution or way?

Comment: You may find this an interesting background read https://dhenrie0208.wordpress.com/projects/bad-iphone-ssids-explained/ it will not fix it as it assumes Windows!